# ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughCantAssociateThroughHasOneOrManyReflection Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model Job, which has_many Applications, and has_many Questions. An Answer belongs to both an Application and a Question.

I'm trying to make a factory method an admin can use to create applications, without users having to write anything.

To do this, I wrote --

```
 def self.make_by_admin(params)
    app = Application.new
    app.user_id = params[:user_id]
    app.job_id = params[:job_id]

    app.questions.each do |question|
      app.answers.new(question_id: question.id, content: 'N/A')
    end

    app
  end
```

But, I get the error

```
#<ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughCantAssociateThroughHasOneOrManyReflection: Cannot modify association 'Application#questions' because the source reflection class 'Question' is associated to 'Job' via :has_many.>
```

What's weird though is that I'm not actually modifying questions. All I want to do is to generate blank answers for each question.

How would I go about doing that?

### Full Models

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope { order('jobs.created_at DESC') }

  has_many :bullets, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :job
  has_many :roles, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :job
  has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :job

  has_many :job_city_relations, inverse_of: :job, dependent: :destroy 
  has_many :cities, through: :job_city_relations
  has_many :job_industry_relations, inverse_of: :job, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :industries, through: :job_industry_relations
  has_many :applications, inverse_of: :job, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users,  through: :applications

  validates :cities, 
    :job_title,
    :job_summary,
    :qualifications,
    :industries,
    :bullets, 
    :roles, 
    :questions, 
    presence: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bullets, 
    reject_if:  :all_blank, 
    allow_destroy:  true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :roles,
    reject_if: :all_blank, 
    allow_destroy:  true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, 
    reject_if: :all_blank,
    allow_destroy:  true

  scope :with_cities, ->(city) do
    job =  Job
      .includes(:industries)
      .includes(:cities)
      .includes(:questions)
      .includes(:bullets)
      .includes(:roles)

    job = job.where(cities: { id: city })  if city 

    job
  end

  scope :with_search, ->(search) do
    job = Job.includes(:industries)
      .includes(:cities)
      .includes(:bullets)
      .includes(:roles)
      .includes(:questions)

    if search
      job = job.where('jobs.job_title LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
    end

    job
  end

  scope :with_info, -> do
    Job.includes(:industries)
       .includes(:cities)
       .includes(:bullets)
       .includes(:roles)
       .includes(:questions)
  end

  def self.build
    job = Job.new

    2.times {
      job.bullets.build
      job.roles.build
    }  

    job.questions.build
    job
  end

  def potentials
    good_fits = User.includes(:source, :heat, :applications, common_app: [:cities, :industries]) 
      .where('cities.id IN (?)', self.city_ids)
      .where('industries.id IN (?)', self.industry_ids)
      .where('users.id NOT IN (?)', self.users.map(&:id))
  end
end
```

---

```
class Application < ActiveRecord::Base  
  STATUS_OPTIONS = ["Application Complete",
    "Materials Submitted",
    "Pending Interview",
    "Second Interview"]

  belongs_to :job, counter_cache: true
  belongs_to :user, counter_cache: true
  has_many :questions, through: :job
  has_many :answers, inverse_of: :application, dependent: :destroy

  validates :job_id, presence: true 
  validates :user_id, presence: true 
  validates :answers, presence: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers,
   allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank

  scope :with_dependents, -> do
    Application
       .includes(:job)
       .includes(:questions)
       .includes(:answers)
  end

  scope :for_job, ->(job_id) do
    Application
      .includes(user: [:source, :heat, common_app: [:cities, :industries]])
      .includes(questions: :answer)
      .where('applications.job_id = ?', job_id)
  end

  def self.build(job, appl = Application.new)
    job.questions.each do |question|
      appl.answers.build(question_id: question.id)
    end

    appl
  end

  def self.make_by_admin(params)
    app = Application.new
    app.user_id = params[:user_id]
    app.job_id = params[:job_id]

    app.questions.each do |question|
      app.answers.new(question_id: question.id, content: 'N/A')
    end

    fail
    app
  end
```

### end

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :job
    has_one :answer
```

### end

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :application
end
```

Comment: Can you share the models Job , Application, Question and Answer in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing

```
  def self.make_by_admin(params)
    app = Application.new
    app.user_id = params[:user_id]
    app.job_id = params[:job_id]

    app.questions.pluck(:id).each do |id|
      app.answers.new(question_id: id, content: 'N/A')
    end

    app
  end
```